# DB-Translations Extract in Symfony2 fails abruptly saying 'killed'

Tags: git, symfony

I am running the following command.

```
php app/console translation:extract ${culture} --output-format=xlf --bundle=BundleName --enable-extractor=db_translations
```

And I am seeing following errors.

```
Extracting translation keys
Extracting messages from directory : /var/www/symfony/src
Extracting messages with custom extractor : db_translations
Killed
```

Comment: It appears you're running out of memory. Are there any additional log statements available ? Is the bundle unusually large ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to increase the memory size from Vagrant file and reboot my VM box.

```
# Modify virtualbox config.
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2", "--cpuexecutioncap", "100", "--memory", "10240"]
    vb.name = "Max on Ubuntu 14.04"
```

It worked fine with extracting translations.